# Symfony get current URI slugs as array?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In Symfony, how do you get the current URI slugs as an array?

```
www.mysite.com/this/that/test/hello/world/7?whatever=true
```

What command is used to get the following array:

```
[0] => 'this',
[1] => 'that',
[2] => 'test',
[3] => 'hello',
[4] => 'world',
[5] => '7'
```

Comment: What Symfony-Version are you talking about and can what does your action look like at the moment?

Comment: 1.4. My action is empty at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
explode('/', $request->getPathInfo());
```

(I don't actually know where you'll get your request object from, so you'll may have to rename the variable)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 explode('/',$this->getContext()->getRouting()->getCurrentInternalUri());
```